# How to use keyTextTransform() for nested json?

Tags: json, django, postgresql

My model has a json field. I can access jsonfield['key1'] with the following query

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb import KeyTextTransform
MyModel.objects.annotate(val=KeyTextTransform('key1', 'jsonfield')).order_by('val')
```

But how can I access a key like jsonfield['key1']['key2'] or even more nested ones?

This can't be the only solution, right?

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(val=KeyTextTransform('key2', (KeyTextTransform('key1', 'jsonfield'))).order_by('val')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The hard part is already done, thankfully. `KeyTextTransform` is composable. All we have to do is compose it.

```py
class NestableKeyTextTransform:
    def __new__(cls, field, *path):
        if not path:
            raise ValueError("Path must contain at least one key.")
        head, *tail = path
        field = KeyTextTransform(head, field)
        for head in tail:
            field = KeyTextTransform(head, field)
        return field


MyModel.objects.annotate(
    single_nested_value=NestableKeyTextTransform(
      "json_field", "query", "name"
    ),
    array_access=NestableKeyTextTransform(
      "json_field", "query", "address_line", 1
    ),
)
```

Though I would like to point out that this may be a better way to do it:

```py
from django.db.models import F

MyModel.objects.annotate(
    single_nested_value=F("json_field__query__name"),
    array_access=F("json_field__query__address_line__1"),
)
```

Answer (score 4):

NB as of the start of 2023 (in django's development version) you can now also do:

```py
from django.db.models.fields.json import KT
Dogs.objects.annotate(
     first_breed=KT("data__breed__1"),
     owner_name=KT("data__owner__name")
)
```

See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#kt-expressions) and [feature request](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33966)